# Scraping - catch json response with python

Tags: json, ajax, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I need to scrape a website with a "load more" button. 
I need to catch the json response (which is invisible in the html code) and parse it to build URLs

This is the JSON post request response

[image]

I'm using Selenium, python.
how do I ?
tHX

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve] for guidance on posting. There should be evidence of what you have researched, where you are stuck with your coding, relevant HTML can be included using the snippet tool via [edit]. Please include the URL if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass actually clicking on the "load more" button by reading the API call that the website is sending when you click the button and then sending it via Selenium. If you send it through Selenium, you can capture the response. Here's what I've been using an Angular website. You'll have to modify it to work with the website you're using, but this should get you started.

```
    call = """
        $http = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http');

        var done = arguments[0];

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            data: {
                foo: "bar"
            },
            url: "https://request.url/"
        }).then(data => done(data));

    """
    json_response = driver.execute_async_script(call)
```

The `execute_async_script` method will make the call and wait for a JSON response.

You can also right-click on the xhr in Chrome DevTools and copy the API call, which should make it easier to recreate it with selenium.

Let me know if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: what is the diffrence between call and url variables ? In wich one I must put the api call ? what contains the url variable ? what is $http ? could it be "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-name='load_more']").click();" in my case ? data variable what should it contain ? Thx